# How to get Tapped Command when clicking or touching an item in the List using MAUI MVVM?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, maui

I am having a hard time finding a way how to do this and its been 3 days and I cant figure it out. I am just trying to find a way when I click or tap any item in the list I want to fire a Command or Method so I can write my code.

**XAML**

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Productos}" HasUnevenRows="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" 
          RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshLoading}" ItemTapped="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <!-- ... -->
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Code behind** with MVVM using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;

public partial class InventarioViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    // prods
    [ObservableProperty]
    List<Productos> _productos = new List<Productos>();
    
    [ObservableProperty]
    private Productos _selectedItem;
    
    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool _isRefreshLoading = false;
    
    public InventarioViewModel(ILoginService loginService)
    {
        _loginService = loginService;
    
        Task.Run(async () => { await CargarProductos(); });      
    }  
    
    private async Task CargarProductos()
    {
        // code for loading products
    }         
    
    // here is here i wanna trigger when I click or tap any item
    // in the list but i cannot make this work
    [RelayCommand]
    void ItemTapped()
    {
        // Handle the ItemTapped event here
    }
}
```

**Inventario.cs**

```cs
public partial class Inventario : ContentPage
{
    public Inventario(InventarioViewModel vm)
    {
        BindingContext = vm;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
        
    private void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

The way I have does not work. All I am looking is just `ItemTapped()` to be fired after clicking or selecting any item in the list but I also need to capture the Product information tapped.

I tried this way:

```
<ListView ItemTappedCommand="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}"></ListView>
```

but says xaml error :

> The property ItemTappedCommand was not found in ListView.

Comment: ItemTapped is an event, not a command.  You can use EventToCommandBehavior to convert it to a command, or just use an event handler

Comment: can you show me a solution? I am totally new into MAUI I have done a lot of things so far but this ListView got me so hard

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/event-to-command-behavior

Comment: Or simply have the event handle call the VM command

Comment: Can you give me a bit more details about the second one? using a hanlder I know how to make a handler like `ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)` but how do I link with InventarioViewModel? because that handling method is outside from InventarioViewModel or did I understood wrong?

Comment: Your page has to have a reference to its VM, either explicitly or via its BindingContext

Comment: It already does and I Updated my question including the Event method you told me. I updated it but I am a bit lost.

Comment: This is a similar question, but the answer is pretty much the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74969968/net-maui-binding-itemselected-event-of-listview-to-viewmodel/74970311#74970311

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, keep a reference to your VM

```
InventarioViewModel VM;

public Inventario(InventarioViewModel vm)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = ViewModel = vm;
}
```

then in your event handler you can call a method or command on your VM (you will need to make `ItemTapped` public)

```
private void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    VM.ItemTapped(...);
}
```

Comment: man I am sure that there are a lot of people struggling with this problem too. Only if Microsoft fixes this `ItemTapped` as `ItemTappedCommand` to make this easier because I think most of the software apps have tappable lists. anyway wow thanks! you are a hero!

Comment: No, that should not be fixed or changed. Commands are commonly used in ViewModels, event handlers are commonly used in a View's code behind. Those are distinct scenarios and it's up to the developer to decide how to use each. That's why there's the `EventToCommandBehavior`. If at all, an `ItemTappedCommand` could be added to the `ListView` control, but the event should not be replaced by a command.

Comment: I thought all the stuff even including the events should be managed inside the ViewModel that is why I was struggling. Thanks for the information now I am more confident with MAUI.

Comment: Event handlers for View events cannot exist in ViewModels, because that would violate the MVVM design pattern since ViewModels must not know anything about Views (nor event arguments that belong to a View). Events are bound to the View. Commands invert that dependency, so that the ViewModel provides a way to call a method without subscribing to a View's event.