# How to know if a control is visible or not?

Tags: c#, maui

I have a first page as disclaimer, and I would like to know if the user read all the conditions before anabling the buttons to can acept or cancel.

This page, I have many labels with the text, one label for each paragrah.

At first, the last label is not visible, so the user has to scroll until the end to can see it. So I was thinking that one way to know if the user read all the text it could be checking if this last label is visible or not.

So I have this code:

View model:

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="*, AUTO"
              BackgroundColor="CornflowerBlue">
        <ScrollView Padding="10,10,10,10">

    <VerticalStackLayout>

        <!--Many labels-->

        <!--My last label, not visible at first.-->
        <Label Margin="0,5,0,0"
            Text="Some text."
            IsVisible="{Binding IsLastLabelVisible}"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Start" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Grid ColumnDefinitions="1*, 1*" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,20,0,10">
        <Button Text="Acept" Margin="20,0,20,0"
                IsEnabled="{Binding IsActionsEnabled}"/>

    <Button Text="Cancel" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20,0,20,0"
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsActionsEnabled}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

View model:

```
//I am using CommunityToolkit.MVVM
[ObservableProperty]
bool _isLastLabelVisible;

partial void OnIsLastLabelVisibleChanged(bool value)
{
    if(IsActionsEnabled == false)
    {
        IsActionsEnabled = value;
    }
}




[ObservableProperty]
bool _isActionsEnabled;
```

The problem is that this last label is not visible when I scroll to the end, so it is not notify when it is visble.

So, how could I know that I scroll to the end to can enable the actions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect if the scrollview scroll to the end or not by following code:

Add a padding for the scrollview in the xamal to make it can be detected when it scrolls to the end :

```
<ScrollView Scrolled="ScrollView_Scrolled" Grid.Row="0" Padding="0,0,0,1">
```

And do the work you want in the scrolled event:

```
   private void ScrollView_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
    {
            var scrollview = (ScrollView)sender;
            if(e.ScrollY >= (scrollview.ContentSize.Height - scrollview.Height))//scroll to the end
            {
                  // do the job here
            }
    }
```

And I see you used the databinding. You can use the [EventToCommandBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/event-to-command-behavior) to convert the scrollview's scrolled event to command.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This solution uses code behind, and in my case i would prefer if it would be possible in a MVVM solution.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply and you can refer to this answer about [the event in the MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74970311/17455524). And my solution need the `ScrolledEventArgs` which has no convertor in the toolkit. I think the event handler is better than the command. Or maybe there is a better method than mine to  detect if the scrollview scroll to the end or not. @ÁlvaroGarcía